# Power automate to move values between tables

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, dataverse

I am making a model driven power app using dataverse tables. I have a central table, 'Project Hub', and another table 'form 1'. What I want to do is create a power automate flow that when a user sets the column 'Status' to live in the project hub table, A row should be added to form one, the 'Project Name' from 'Project hub' should be copied into that new row in 'form one' in the column of the same name and the due date for that row in form one should be set to 90 days after the flow is tirggered.

I have figured out the trigger for the flow and how to add a new row to 'form 1' but I still need to get the value from the 'Project Hub' "project name" column and add it to the 'form 1' row and also the due date part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.